# How to fix the shrink and flatten tool mistakes in this chair model?

Tags: modeling

I wanted to model a simple chair for a blender exercise, I loop cut a cube then scale it to be flatter. But after using shrink and flatten tool, my "chair" looks like this :-
[image]

But what I wanted to make it look like this :-
[image]

Anyone got any ideas why the middle sections are scaled along with the selected face?

Comment: if you want it to look like your second image, use extrusions, not shrink/fatten

Comment: Ah, silly me. Should have known that extrude is the right tool to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have no reason to use *Shrink/Fatten* here, instead use extrusion, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]